# ORACLE SQL - analytical function (two ORDER BYs)

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am trying to figure out the sequence of flow in the event of two "ORDER BY" in one statement.

I have a table with one field (GS_SEC) with auto-generated values, beginning with 156759 and ending with 32123087.

- **GS_SEC**
- 156759
- 156760
- 156761
- .....
- 32123087

QUERY 1:

```
select GS_SEC, 
        max(GS_SEC) over (),
        avg(GS_SEC) OVER (ORDER BY GS_SEC DESC ) AS AAA 
from tblgs_reference  
where rownum < 11
```

QUERY 2:

```
select GS_SEC, 
       max(GS_SEC) over (), 
       avg(GS_SEC) OVER (ORDER BY GS_SEC DESC ) AS AAA
from tblgs_reference
where rownum < 11 
order by  GS_SEC DESC
```

For query 1, I got a result showing the largest 10 GS_SEC values in descending order + maximum value as 32123094 + decreasing average value beginning with 32123094.

**Question A**: Is the decreasing display order of the result set caused by the "DESC" of the "ORDER BY GS_SEC DESC" ?

For query 2, I got a result showing the smallest 10 GS_SEC values in decreasing order + maximum value as 156768 + decreasing average value beginning with 156768.

**Question B**: When the AVG function is invoked in calculation, does ORACLE process the records beginning from "156759" or "156768" ?

**Question C**: Am I right to say that the "order by  GS_SEC DESC" in the last part of the statement is processed last and has no impact to how the analytical function is invoked?

**Question D**: The difference between both queries is just "ORDER BY GS_SEC DESC". Why does it cause a difference such that for query 1, largest ten GS_SEC values are returned whereas smallest 10 GS_SEC values are returned for query 2?

Comment: If your values begin from 156759, how do you get records beginning with 156758 and decreasing? (Question B).

Comment: Question A: - the order you see is pure coincidence and can change at any time because the overall query has no `order by` statement.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your observation on other tables. The result is different only when there is an index on the column you use in your query (when there is no index, the highest values are returned by both queries). Regardless of why this happens (which has to do with the way Oracle wrote its code), you should not rely on this behavior. `where rownum < 11` in the main query will return 10 **random** rows from the base table, that is the only thing that is guaranteed. Keep in mind that `where` is processed before `select` and before `order by`.